G has a composition series if and only if G has only finitely many distinct subnormal subgroups
How do you prove that if a group $G$ has a composition series, then $G$ has only finitely many distinct subnormal subgroups?
It seems that you have to proceed by induction by showing that there is only finitely many maximal normal subgroups. But I cannot see the way to do it.

Show first that is $M$ and $N$ are maximal normal subgroups of $G$ then $G/M \times N$ has only finitely many maximal normal subgroups. Using that you can prove it by induction on composition length.

@DerekHolt: Should be $G/M \cap N$?

In any case, the crucial case is when $G$ has two composition factors.

@testaccount Yes of course, thanks!
